# Upgrading MVC 3 to MVC 6 What is the best way

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am planning to upgrade MVC3 EF5 project to MVC6.  I understand it will require a lot of manual changes all over in config files, project files, entity framework, etc. Before I spend hours, wanted to see what is the best way?

**Option 1**:  to make changes in IDs, configures, assemblies, etc. in the existing project (it doesn't even open in VS2015 right now, like any other MVC3 project, Thank You Microsoft).  Looking at the instructions for converting MVC3 to MVC4/5, I guess I will need to have an ambulance on the standby here :-)  It amazes me that MS did not provide any tool or even clear instructions to help developers.

**Option 2**:  Create a brand new project in VS2015, then add new controllers with the same name as found in the old projects, then copy and paste controller implementations.  Views and non-controller classes should work without much changes (only change I can think of is that new versions of dependencies in imports may be incompatible and will need to be dealt with manually, but this would be the same in Option 1).  Not sure how to deal with entity framework. Perhaps if I recreate the entity model from database again, it should generate a   compatible code. But then there are probably about 100 stored procedure function imports. I guess I will need to create function imports manually one by one (Question here, will the existing function imports remain intact if Option 1 is followed? Is there a way to copy function imports from the old project?).

Sorry, I know this is a rather convoluted question.  Just trying to solicit inputs from others who may have done this in the past.  I understand both Option 1 and 2 will require hours of work.

Comment: PS: If you don't know the answer or/and have nothing to contribute in words, positive or negative, please move on instead of clicking on down arrow.  Thank you.

Comment: Step one is probably to run the Portability tool: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1177943e-cfb7-4822-a8a6-e56c7905292b